# Trying to do multicoloured 3d bar chart in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a 3d bar chart in R, similar to [image]

Generated in Python.

Key points:

I have a dataframe, X, which dictates X,Y coordinates and the Z value of the bar. The *colour* of the bar is dictated by a second data frame.

Does anyone have a pointer as to how I miught do this in R? I've been looking at LatticeExtra but it doesnt seem to give me the capacity to do multiple colours. My solution in Python (where Matplotlib renders it badly and thus not useable) is to generate 3 plots ontop of each other.

I've been playing around with lattice extra and I'm getting closer:

```
d
x  y    z
1 t1  5 high
2 t1  2  low
3 t1  4  med
4 t2  8 high
5 t2  1  low
6 t2  3  med
7 t3 50 high
8 t3 12  med
9 t3 35  low

xx<-d[1:5,]
zz<-d[6:9,]

cloud(y~x+z, xx, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='green', 
  xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), 
  par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),zlim=c(0,100))+  as.layer(
  cloud(y~x+z, zz, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='red',
  xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1),
  par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),zlim=c(0,100)))
```

But the issue I'm struggling with now is setting the `xlim` to correspond to the full range of values

Pointers would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you have a reason for this, but are you really sure a 3d-barchart is the way to go? I find your example very hard to interpret.

Comment: Before trying to replicate this in R, you should ask yourself whether there is a better way to visualize your data.

Comment: Requirements as provided to me sadly (isnt that always the case !) I am open to other ways of presenting the data, however - the key thing for this demonstration is to show the size of the market and a risk position (the colour) of a particular market. I considered heat maps but that made it hard to visualise both facts I need.

Comment: Why not for instance a faceted plot? Along the lines of `ggplot(d, aes(x=z, y=y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~x)`?

Comment: The example data I've provided is only a small set of data. the 6x6 plot above is also only a small set of data - the currency trading position may run into dozens or hundreds of currency pairs so I'm not sure your solution would scale well?

Comment: Is this not simply a scatterplot with size?

Comment: I don't know, but the 3dplot has the same limitation. Thinking about it, @zx8754's solution will scale better.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by scatterplot with size? A scatter plot would be one way to present this, you mean setting the marker size to be proportional to the market size, and then colouring the marker depending on risk position? I think that could work

Comment: See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_point.html - `geom_point(aes(size = qsec))`

Comment: I have added the code for a scatterplot using dummy-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on @zx-approach of a scatterplot, using some generated data:

```
set.seed(123)
currency <- LETTERS[1:10]

dat <- expand.grid(c1=currency, c2=currency)
dat$value <- runif(nrow(dat),min=0,max=150) #changed limits to allow for legend-illustration
dat$category <- factor(sample(c("low","mid","high"),nrow(dat),T),levels=c("low","mid","high")) #ordered factor for nicer plot


p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=c1, y=c2, size=value, color=category)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(name="Risk level",values=c(low="green",mid="orange",high="red")) +#set colors and name for aestethic color
  scale_size_continuous(name="Market size", breaks=c(25,50,75,100,125),labels=c('25','50','75','100','125'))
p1
```

[image]

I've edited to customize the legend. The 'scale' might be a bit counter-intuitive, but it does indeed deal with aestethics and legends (and also with axes. You'll get used to it if you use more ggplot, sorry).

Comment: Thanks. This does pretty much what I'm looking for. What I'm struggling with now is trying to rename the legend. Following instructions here dont seem to work: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/
My code is loosely `yy+scale_fill_discrete(name='Market Size GBP Billions',breaks=c(25,50,75,100,125),labels=c('25','50','75','100','125'))`, but the legend titles dont change

Comment: Don't you need `scale_size_` for this?

Comment: Dont know! I have no experience with ggplot2 :-) Pointers to the right direction, thus, appreciated. I'll look at scale size

Comment: Generally, if you need to edit the legend, you need to do it for the scale you're using (be it fill, color, size or alpha). Sorry, didn't realize you were inexperienced with ggplot.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sorry for being dumb. I'm trying to use this now, but if I do `yy+scale_size(c('Market Size','Risk Level'))` it only fixes the Market size label and not the risk level one. Do you have any pointers as to how one adjusts two labels?

Comment: No worries. You're not dumb, and we're all here to learn. To edit two legends, you'll need to edit two scales. I'll edit my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks. It just strikes me as, at least, not being intuitive, and at worst, being counter intuitive. I dont see how `scale_size` relates to the legend at all (at face value I take that to relate to the axis)... :-)

Comment: See my edits. You're right about it being not intuitive, but it'll change after you get the hang of ggplot (If you decide to use it more)

Comment: Thanks :-) Works now. Appreciate your help.